# instagram web api net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Tags: api, npm, electron, instagram, response

I have created a simple photo gallery by a hashtag

Using [instagram-web-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-web-api) and [electron](https://www.electronjs.org)

Main process:

```
const Instagram = require('instagram-web-api')
const client = new Instagram({})
ipc.on('get-photos', (event, hashtagFromClient) => {
createPhotoArray()

async function createPhotoArray() {
    let photoArray = []

    let p = await client.getPhotosByHashtag({ hashtag: hashtagFromClient })

    for (let i = 0; i < p.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_media.edges.length; i++) {
        photoArray.push([p.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_media.edges[i].node.thumbnail_src, p.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_media.edges[i].node.edge_liked_by.count])
    }

    event.sender.send('gallery-created', photoArray)
}
})
```

Render process:

```
ipc.send('get-photos', game.userData.hashtag)

ipc.on('gallery-created', function (event, photoArr) {
    photoArray = photoArr
    maxNumIMG = photoArray.length
    for (let i = 0; i < photoArray.length; i++) {
        myTimeout = setTimeout(function () { createNewPhoto(photoArray[i][0]) }, gapTime * i)
    }
})
```

But I see the floating error:

```
net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67293454/15404876 Here is the code which mitigates the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Instagram has changed it's CORS policy recently. You have to set the request header Host to bypass the policy.

Comment: Can you explain some example?

Comment: I am very appreciated. I am very appreciated. Could you show some example please